# Accessing Jquery variable for d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I want to get a variable from a jquery function to plug into d3, but I can’t access it. This is what I have and the variable I’m having problems with is yearSelected.  I'm just trying to capture yearSelected to write to the console for now.

```
var yearSelected = "";
    $(function () {      
        $("#slider").slider({
            value: 100,
            min: 2000,
            max: 2013,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#year").val(ui.value);
                yearSelected = ui.value;
            }
        });
        $("#year").val($("#slider").slider("value"));

        return yearSelected;
    });

    console.log(yearSelected);
```

Comment: You don't explain how you want to use this with D3.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

I want to update my d3 chloropeth map based on the year from the Jquery slider.

Comment: Well you have that value available in `ui.value` -- all you need to do is call a function that does the update with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(function(){})` is a shorthand for `$.documentReady(function(){})` call - it registers the DOMContentLoaded listener.

Problems:

1. Listeners cannot return values (it is pointless).
2. Your code is **asynchronous**: you try to access the `yearSelected` value right after registering the listener, but the listener is fired only **when DOM is constructed**! 
   Is it clear?

   1. Main JS code is evaluated when the script is loaded and **evaluated**
   2. Listener function is evaluated only after the whole DOM content is available (**much later** than main script is evaluated)

**One easy way to make a workaround**: incorporate your logic (`console.log`) in your example into the listener function (where your slider is initialized).

P.S. this approach is leading to the problem called **'javascript callback hell'**, but this is another story...